# Tabla NO se actualiza

Tags: mysql-workbench, netbeans-8.2

Buenas noches: estoy haciendo un programa para una *PARRILLA* en el cual tengo las siguientes tablas

*Pedidos* definida de la siguiente manera

```
CREATE TABLE `pedido` (
  `numpedido` int not null primary key auto_increment,
  `fecha` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idempleado` int(4) not NULL,
   constraint `idemp`
   foreign key (`idempleado`) references `empleado`(`codempleado`),
  `idcliente` int(6) not NULL,
    constraint `idcli`
   foreign key (`idcliente`) references `cliente`(`codcliente`),
  `idmesa` int(6) not NULL,
   constraint `idme`
   foreign key (`idmesa`) references `mesa`(`codmesa`)
);
```

*Detalle_Pedidos*

```
CREATE TABLE `detalle_pedido` (
  `idpedido` int(4) not null,
   constraint `idpe`
   foreign key (`idpedido`) references `pedido`(`numpedido`),
  `idcomida` int(4) not NULL,
   constraint `idcom`
   foreign key (`idcomida`) references `comida`(`codcomida`),
  `cantidad` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

y otra tabla *Listar_Pedidos*

```
 CREATE TABLE `listar_pedido` (
  `numpedido` int(4) not null,
  `fecha` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idempleado` int(4) not NULL,
  `idcliente` int(6) not NULL,
  `idmesa` int(6) not NULL,
  `TOTAL`float(9,2) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

tengo un formulario *FrmListadoPedidos* (el cual muestra los pedidos, el monto por pedido y el monto total de TODOS los pedidos)

```
package Formularios;
import Base.ConectaBD;
import static Formularios.FrmConsultaPedido.jTblDetalle;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class FrmListadoPedidos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
//                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jTblConsultaProductos.getModel();

   java.text.DecimalFormat formatoSalidaDecimal = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00");
   ConectaBD cnx = new ConectaBD();
   Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
   SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   String sql = "Select * from listar_pedido";

   public void LimpiarTabla(DefaultTableModel model) {
       for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           model.removeRow(i);
       }
   }

   public void icono() {
       Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/003-navegador.png"));
       setIconImage(icon);
       setVisible(true);
   }

   public void LLenarTabla(String sql) {
       try {
           cnx.rs = cnx.stm.executeQuery(sql);
           DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) this.jTblPedido.getModel();
           LimpiarTabla(model);
           while (cnx.rs.next()) {
               String col1 = cnx.rs.getString(1);
               String col2 = cnx.rs.getString(2);
               String col3 = cnx.rs.getString(3);
               String col4 = cnx.rs.getString(4);
               String col5 = cnx.rs.getString(5);
               String col6 = cnx.rs.getString(6);

               Vector vRow = new Vector();
               vRow.addElement(col1);
               vRow.addElement(col2);
               vRow.addElement(col3);
               vRow.addElement(col4);
               vRow.addElement(col5);
               vRow.addElement(col6);
               model.addRow(vRow);
           }
       } catch (SQLException a) {
           System.out.println(a);
       }
   }

   public void limpiarTabla(DefaultTableModel model) {
       for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           model.removeRow(i);
       }
   }

   public void Llenartabla1(String con_sql) {
       int Col11 = 1;
       try {
           cnx.rs = cnx.stm.executeQuery(con_sql);
           DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jTblConsultaProductos.getModel();
           limpiarTabla(model);
           while (cnx.rs.next()) {

               String Col0 = cnx.rs.getString(2);
               String Col1 = cnx.rs.getString(3);
               String Col2 = cnx.rs.getString(4);

               Vector vRow = new Vector();
               vRow.addElement(Col11);
               vRow.addElement(Col0);
               vRow.addElement(Col1);
               vRow.addElement(Col2);
               model.addRow(vRow);
               Col11++;
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }

   public void MostrarProducto() {
       String cod, sql1;
       try {
           cod = this.jTblPedido.getValueAt(this.jTblPedido.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
           
      //     sql1 = "SELECT * FROM listar_pedido WHERE numpedido='" + cod + "'";
           
           sql1 = " select distinct lp.numpedido as `nro_pedido`, lp.fecha as `fecha_pedido`, \n" +
                  " e.nombre as `empleado`, c.nombre as `cliente`, m.descripcion as `mesa`,\n" +
                  " (select det.cantidad * det.precio from detalle_pedido as det LIMIT 1) AS `total`\n" +
                  " from listar_pedido as lp\n" +
                  " JOIN detalle_pedido AS det ON lp.numpedido = det.idpedido\n" +
                  " JOIN empleado AS e ON lp.idempleado = e.codempleado\n" +
                  " JOIN cliente AS c ON lp.idcliente = c.codcliente\n" +
                  " JOIN mesa AS m ON lp.idmesa = m.codmesa where lp.numpedido = '" + cod + "' ";
           
             
           String sql2 = "select * from detalle_pedido where idpedido='" + cod + "'";
           cnx.rs = cnx.stm.executeQuery(sql1);
           
           if (cnx.rs.next()) {
               FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jLblCodPedido.setText(cnx.rs.getString(1));
               FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jLblFecha.setText(cnx.rs.getString(2));
               FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jLblCliente.setText(cnx.rs.getString(4));
               FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jLblEmpleado.setText(cnx.rs.getString(3));
               FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jLblMesa.setText(cnx.rs.getString(5));
               Llenartabla1(sql2);

               double total = 0, Total = 0;
               for (int fila = 0; fila <= FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jTblConsultaProductos.getRowCount() - 1; fila++) {
                   String col2 = FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jTblConsultaProductos.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString();
                   String col3 = FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jTblConsultaProductos.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString();
                   total = Double.parseDouble(col3) * Integer.parseInt(col2);
                   Total = Total + total;
               }
               FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido.jLblMontoTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Total));
           }
       } catch (Exception a) {
           System.out.println(a.getMessage());
       }
   }

   public void CalcularTotal() {
       double total = 0;
       double ti;
       for (int fila = 0; fila <= this.jTblPedido.getRowCount() - 1; fila++) {
           total = total + Double.parseDouble(this.jTblPedido.getValueAt(fila, 5).toString());
       }
       formatoSalidaDecimal.format(total);
       this.jLblMonto.setText(String.valueOf(formatoSalidaDecimal.format(total)));

   }

   public FrmListadoPedidos() {
       initComponents();
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
       this.setResizable(false);
       this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
   }
                     

   private void JBTNMOSTRARActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
       String sql = "";
       if (this.JRBFecha.isSelected() == false && this.JRBEntre.isSelected() == false) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecione un Criterio de la Fecha", "Consulta de Empleados", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
           return;
       }
       if (this.JRBFecha.isSelected()) {
           sql = "SELECT * from listar_pedido where fecha='" + date.format(this.jDFechaEspecifica.getDate()) + "'";
       } else {
           sql = "SELECT * FROM listar_pedido where fecha Between '" + date.format(this.jDcEntre.getDate()) + "' and '" + date.format(this.jDcAl.getDate()) + "'";
       }

       this.LLenarTabla(sql);
       CalcularTotal();
   }                                           

   private void JBTNSALIRActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
       int r;
       r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Cerrar Programa", "Salir", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
       if (r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
           dispose();
       }
   }                                         

   private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
       cnx.conectar();
       this.jDFechaEspecifica.setDate(now);
       this.jDcEntre.setDate(now);
       this.jDcAl.setDate(now);
       LLenarTabla(sql);
       CalcularTotal();
       icono();
   }                                 

   private void JBTNSALIR1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
       LLenarTabla(sql);
       CalcularTotal();
       this.jDFechaEspecifica.setDate(now);
       this.jDcAl.setDate(now);
       this.jDcEntre.setDate(now);
   }                                          

   private void jTblPedidoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
       FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido frm_agregar_producto = new FrmCampodeBusquedaPedido();
       MostrarProducto();
       frm_agregar_producto.show();
   }                                       

   private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
       //cnx.conectar();
       //  CalcularTotal();
   }                                    

   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
   public static void main(String args[]) {

       /* Create and display the form */
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               new FrmListadoPedidos().setVisible(true);
           }
       });
   }  
}
```

El problema que se me presenta es al momento de ingresar un nuevo pedido, la tabla no se actualiza con los datos de ese *nuevo pedido* (estoy tomando como base un proyecto pero que es para un *restaurante*, en el cual el Formulario de Listar_Pedidos en el método *MostrarProducto()* la consulta sql que ejecuta es: sql1 = "SELECT * FROM listar_pedido WHERE numpedido='" + cod + "'"; dicha tabla listar_pedido no estaba en la base de datos entonces la cree y al momento de ejecutar me mostraba vacío) lo que intenté es lo siguiente:

```
insert into `listar_pedido` (`numpedido`,`fecha`,`idempleado`,`idcliente`,`idmesa`,`TOTAL`)
  select `numpedido`, `fecha`, `idempleado`, `idcliente`, `idmesa`, (select  det.cantidad*det.precio from 
  detalle_pedido as det )
  from`pedido`;
  
  select distinct lp.numpedido as `nro_pedido`, lp.fecha as `fecha_pedido`, 
                  e.nombre as `empleado`, c.nombre as `cliente`, m.descripcion as `mesa`, 
                  (select det.cantidad*det.precio from detalle_pedido as det LIMIT 1) as `TOTAL` 
                    from listar_pedido as lp
                    JOIN detalle_pedido AS det ON lp.numpedido = det.idpedido
                    JOIN empleado AS e ON lp.idempleado = e.codempleado
                    JOIN cliente AS c ON lp.idcliente = c.codcliente
                    JOIN mesa AS m ON lp.idmesa = m.codmesa group by `nro_pedido`;

(select sum(`TOTAL`) from listar_pedido as lp LIMIT 1);
```

muestra el listado de los pedidos **PERO NO ACTUALIZA** de manera automática la tabla *listar_pedidos* que es lo que necesito, cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Creo que más que nada tienes un error de enfoque en tu aplicación. ¿Qué sentido tiene manejar una tabla `listar_pedido`? El mismo nombre ya indica que se trata de un método, por lo tanto cuando necesites *listar* los pedidos sería cuestión de consultar a la tabla `pedido` (uniéndola con las tablas que necesites para la información de esa lista de pedidos). En la pregunta tampoco queda bien explicado el contexto. Hablas de un formulario listar pedidos, pero no sé que tiene que ver ese formulario con la creación de un nuevo pedido. ¿?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas INSERT el resultado solo sera INSERTAR nuevos registros pero no actualizarlos.

Si la tabla `listar_pedido` no existia puede que se haya creado como vista (VIEW), la cual es una  vista generada (comomuna tabla virtual) en base a una consulta como la que usas en el insert (y que se actualiza automaticamente).

Por tanto, la primera opcion seria asegurarte de que la tabla esta actualizada siempre antes de usarla:

```
TRUNCATE `listar_pedido`;

insert into `listar_pedido` (`numpedido`,`fecha`,`idempleado`,`idcliente`,`idmesa`,`TOTAL`)
  select `numpedido`, `fecha`, `idempleado`, `idcliente`, `idmesa`, (select  det.cantidad*det.precio from 
  detalle_pedido as det )
  from`pedido`;
```

Y luego el SELECT.

La otra opcion es crear la vista usando la instruccion CREATE VIEW y luego simplemente usarla en el select (no es necesario actualizarla)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `listar_pedido`; /* eliminar la tabla creada */
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW listar_pedido AS
SELECT `numpedido`, `fecha`, `idempleado`, `idcliente`, `idmesa`, (select  det.cantidad*det.precio from 
  detalle_pedido as det )
  from`pedido`;
```

Esto ultimo se debe hacer solo una vez, y luego simplemente usar `listar_pedido` en una consulta SELECT (no es actualizable manualmente). Si deseas actualizar o cambiar las columnas de la vista, o la logica de esta, simplemente volver a crear la vista con `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ...`

Comment: tengo una consulta respecto a la vista creada, en el formulario tengo que filtrar la misma mediante 2 jradiobutton (cada uno con un jdatechooser) y un jbutton de acuerdo a una fecha especifica o rango de fechas pero al seleccionar uno de los jradiobutton y hacer clic en el jbutton los datos cargados desaparecen, cómo puedo solucionar este problema? @F.Igor

Comment: ```if (this.JRBFecha.isSelected() == false && this.JRBEntre.isSelected() == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecione un Criterio de la Fecha", "Consulta de Empleados", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            return; }
        if (this.JRBFecha.isSelected()) {
            sql = "SELECT * from `LISTAR_PEDIDOS` where fecha='" + date.format(this.jDFechaEspecifica.getDate()) + "'";
        } else {
            sql = "SELECT * from `LISTAR_PEDIDOS` where fecha Between '" + date.format(this.jDcEntre.getDate()) + "' and '" + date.format(this.jDcAl.getDate()) + "'";}```

Comment: agrega `System.out.println(sql);` despues de este codigo para revisar si la consulta esta usando el formato adecuado para fechas, deben estar en formato 'yyyy-MM-dd'. Supongo que date es un objeto SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Cómo puedo filtrar la tabla comida de acuerdo a la categoría seleccionada en un jcombobox? Con este código me carga el jcombobox pero no logro que al seleccionar me muestre las comidas de esa categoría:```public void CargaCategoria() {
        try {
            cnx.rs = cnx.stm.executeQuery("SELECT nombrecat FROM categoria ORDER BY 1");
            jCboCat.removeAllItems();
            while (cnx.rs.next()) {
                jCboCat.addItem(cnx.rs.getString(2));
            }
        } catch (Exception a) {
            System.out.println(a.getMessage());
        }```

Comment: intenté aplicar sin éxito la respuesta dada en esta consulta: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154000/mostrar-jtable-en-base-a-seleccion-jcombobox] @F.Igor

Comment: Debes realizar una nueva pregunta para lo que estas planteando y colocar alli todos los codigos pertinentes a este nuevo tema, que es totalmente distinto. habran otros que puedan ayudar mejor con el manejo de estos componentes.